# Laravel can I use pivot table as a model

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables **staff**, **customer**, **service**.

I have created pivot for customer and service as **customer_service**(has extra fields).

Now I want to link the staff to customer_service. So i tried to use customer_service as a **model** '**Custserv**' and tried to relate with **staff**. It didnt workout.

Because I don't want staff linking directly to customer and service

I had this following relationship working

```
/*Model - Service*/
public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('customer')->withPivot(
        'start_date',
        'stop_date',
        'rem_date',
        'due_date',
        'status'
        );
}

/*Model - customer*/
public function services(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Service')->withPivot(
        'start_date',
        'stop_date',
        'rem_date',
        'due_date',
        'status'
        );
}

////These following relations didnt workout
/*Model - custserv*/ //uses the pivot table customer_service//
public function staff(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Staff');
}

/*Model - Staff*/
public function custservs(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Custserv');
}

/*schema for pivot table 'staff' and 'Custserv' */
Schema::create('customer_service_user', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('customer_service_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('customer_service_id')->references('id')->on('customer_service')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('staff_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('staff_id')->references('id')->on('staff')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Then I tried ...

```
$staff = User::find(1)->custservs;
return $staff;
```

It gave error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'auditCrm_db.custserv_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select `customer_service`.*, `custserv_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `custserv_user`.`custserv_id` as `pivot_custserv_id` from `customer_service` inner join `custserv_user` on `customer_service`.`id` = `custserv_user`.`custserv_id` where `custserv_user`.`user_id` = 1)
```

If my relationshiop is correct how to get and set values between Staff and Custserv?

Comment: Yes you can. A pivot table is a table in your DB. Extend `Eloquent` and use it

Comment: @AliGajani I have tried and it gave error. check question edit.

Comment: It worked out. I had to follow some naming conventions.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have figured it out, but I think you are doing it overly complicated. When using a many-to-many relationship Laravel provides the [`pivot`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) property. You already have `withPivot` in your relationship.

Now you can access it like that:

```
$staff = User::find(1)->services()->first()->pivot; // or you could loop over services
return $staff;
```

Comment: I tried to figure out the way I understood. I know i did something complicated. Now everything is over my head. I need very good understanding of these complex relations. Guide me if you have nice articles on building big apps on laravel.

Comment: Hmm I would need more information about what you actually need guidance with

Comment: I need best best practices on building database schema and relationship. I have basic knowledge. I have watched most of laracasts.

Comment: I don't have an article at hand, but feel free to ask another question on SO (best would be a rather specific case and the different methods you came up with already)